# Do REST POST action from within HTML

Tags: html, rest

Further to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726368/apache-user-auth-and-redirection-based-on-remote-user, I need to do some `POSTs` to the `REST` API but I'm struggling on how to implement.

I need to do the equivilent of:

```bsh
/usr/bin/curl -s X POST -H "Accept: application/xml" --cacert ca.cer -u user@domain:password -d "<action />" https://server:port/api/id/stop
```

in just plain HTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

No feature of HTML will allow you to construct a request in which you:

- Override the browser's Accept header
- Specify an certificate to use instead of the browser's library of them
- Specify HTTP auth (at least cross browser, some may still accept URIs in the form `http://foo:bar@example.com`) *or*
- Make a POST request with XML as the body

You could specify *some* of that using JavaScript/XHR, but not with "just plain HTML".

Comment: What if I called curl from within the page as maybe a CGI script?  I can't have the whole running as CGI as there's heaps of data to pull off the server and it takes quite a while to get the data from REST.